# Commas after introductory pieces of information

Tags: punctuation, commas

I got confused by the sentence:

> An investigation took place,and five months later Dan was exonerated and returned to active duty.

I wonder whether a comma may(or should) be inserted after the word "later"

Answer (score 1):

It's a matter of style.  If you set off "five months later" with commas, you've got three commas in a short space.  Whether it makes the sentence easier to read is not obvious:

> An investigation took place, and five months later Dan was exonerated
>   and returned to active duty.

A newpaper or a journal may have a style it prefers.  Newspapers are inclined to eliminate commas when they can, because they take space. A comma can cause a paragraph to take up an extra line of type, and a few lines of type is a paragraph that can't be published.

A copy editor of a book often applies a consistent style throughout a book, although it may be based initially on the author's style.  A more open (few commas) style still allows the use of commas essential for meaning and ease of reading.

Just because a phrase can be set off by commas doesn't mean it should be, or that it's unnecessary information; it just means it's not essential to the syntax of the sentence.

Answer (score 0):

> An investigation took place, and, five months later, Dan was exonerated and returned to active duty.

This would be a better way to write. Since *five months later* is unneeded information, you can use commas to offset it from the rest of the sentence.

If you're doing this, you need to place a comma at the end of *later*. Nonessential words or phrases must be closed off.

Comment: Why would you want to put commas on both sides of **and**? This is excessive; **and** is not a clause that can stand alone. If you were speaking, would you pause before *and* after **and**? No! You'd pause either before or after **and**.

Comment: You're welcome to your opinion.